implementing bootstrap-table csv export into angular 15 project
I am trying to implement bootstrab-table table export extension for angular project but havnt been successful so far
https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/export.html
Any help or example would be great help
Thanks in advance
Please is what i have tried in angular project
html file
<div class="container">
<h1>Run Details</h1>

<div id="toolbar">
    <select class="form-control">
    <option value="basic">Export Basic</option>
    <option value="all">Export All</option>
    <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table
    id="table"
    data-toggle="table"
    data-search="true"
    data-flat="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-show-multi-sort="true"
    class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
        <th data-field="project" data-sortable="true">Project</th>
        <th data-field="test_result" data-sortable="true">Hypothesis</th>
        <th data-field="num_passes" data-sortable="true">Run Path</th>
        <th data-field="user_name" data-sortable="true">User Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>

<ngx-spinner type="ball-scale-multiple"></ngx-spinner>

below are the two function which are initializing table
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.runData.length > 0 && !this.isTableInitialized) {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable(
        {
        data:this.runData,
        filterControl: true,
        showSearchClearButton: true,
        search: true,
        showColumns: true,
        showColumnsSearch: true,
        pagination: true,
        exportDataType: 'all',
        showExport: true,
        exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf'],
        }
    );
    this.isTableInitialized = true;
    }
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.spinner.show()
    this.appService.get_data('get_all_runs').subscribe(
    (data:any )=>{

        if (data['result'] == 'SUCCESS'){
        this.runData = data['rows']
        }
        console.log(this.runData )
        this.spinner.hide()
    }, (error)=>{
        console.log(error)
        this.spinner.hide()
    }
    )
}


Try this.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wobvc1?file=package.json
index.html
You must include all these script tags.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.29.0/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.29.0/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.6/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.6/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>

and also include related CSS files inside head tag.
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.6/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css"
/>

main.ts
This includes your code pulling the data from web-server and loading the bootstrap table by below config,
$('#table')
  .bootstrapTable('destroy')
  .bootstrapTable({
    exportDataType: 'all',
    data: this.runData,
    filterControl: true,
    showSearchClearButton: true,
    search: true,
    showColumns: true,
    showColumnsSearch: true,
    pagination: true,
    exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf'],
  });

Reference:
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#extensions/export.html#view-source
NOTE: column name's must match with th's data-field attribute in HTML and runData object's 'rows' array key in typescript.

will this work if i download all scripts and add them to angular.json in script section?

it will not work as it is. I had given an example to understand. Check 'runData' variable in my example, it has keys like 'total', 'totalNotFiltered', and 'rows' as array of objects which is the main data going into the bootstrapTable() as config.
